# Asp.net visible button when 2 parameters match

Tags: c#, asp.net, visibility

Hello I want to make a button visibile when UserId stored in database match with current UserId.

```
            string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            JobDescriptions job = new JobDescriptions();

            if (job.PostedBy == clientId)
            {
                Button2.Visible = true;
            else 
            {
                Button2.Visible = false;
            }
```

PostedBy is the Id of the user who posted on website saved on jobs table. Problem is that button is not visibile when my statement should work.

> The solution

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                JobReqModel model = new JobReqModel();
                JobDescriptions job = model.GetJob(id);

                string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                if (job.PostedBy == clientId)
                {
                    Button2.Visible = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    Button2.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your posted code will only run on the initial load of the page (`!IsPostBack`) - is that your intention?

Comment: I used it to test but If you mentioned now I removed that statement, and I edited the code adding an else and the button is gone everywhere even when my statement should match.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your `JobDescription` class. You aren't actually getting a job from the database to compare to your `clientId`..so whatever the default value of your `JobDescription` (most likely 0) probably doesn't match your `clientId`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, I have solved the problem with help from your suggestion. I will edit in few seconds how I done if everyone get in trouble with this problem.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable, and preferred at Stack Overflow, to add your solution as an answer and mark it as the solution. This is much more preferred than adding an edit to your question with the solution. Consider doing that and glad you got it working.

Comment: u can reduce some line of code by replacing the if condition like below
 Button2.Visible = job.PostedBy == Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();